# Running two scripts on profile login (bash & sudo bash)

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, login, password

I have two scripts which I would like to be run when I log into my profile.

`~/.scripts/startup/user-sensei-raw-startup.sh`:

```
ids=$(xinput list | awk '/SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse .*pointer/ {print $8}' | sed 's/id=\(.*\)/\1/')

if [ -z "$ids" ]; then
  exit 0;
fi

read -a ids_array <<< $ids

echo fixing id ${ids_array[0]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

echo fixing id ${ids_array[1]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

unset ids
unset ids_array
```

`~/.scripts/startup/root-sensei-raw-startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sensei-raw-ctl --show
sensei-raw-ctl --polling 500
sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-on 450
sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-off 5670
```

To run them manually I would run the command when I login:

```
bash ~/.scripts/startup/user-sensei-raw-startup.sh && sudo bash ~/.scripts/startup/root-sensei-raw-startup.sh
```

The first script can be run via `bash` however the other script I need to run via `sudo bash`. Issue is that I must type in my password for the second script to run.

Any ideas of how I can automate this so that I don't have to type in my `sudo` password all the time? I would also prefer not to save my `sudo` password in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bit would be to wrap the entire script, using shc (Bash script compiler).  That way you could use plain text, like `echo password | sudo -S script.sh` in your script.  I suppose someone could decompile, but we're pretty far out there, and then if that's the concern, don't store your sudo password.

Link to SHC.
[shc github](https://github.com/existz/shc-3.8.9)